# How to pass client certificate through HTTP Client in php laravel 8

Tags: php, httpclient, laravel-8, guzzle, client-certificates

How to pass client certificate (2 files .key and .pem) through http client request?
I need to include those files in the below http post request to be able to talk with the server.

```
$response = Http::post('https://domainname.com/api/client/session', array('xxx' => array('xx' => 'xxxx')));
```

I am able to do it using phpCurl like below:

```
$curl = curl_init();
        curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
            CURLOPT_URL => $url,
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
            CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
            CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
            CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
            CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
            CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
            CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => $type,
            CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $body,
            CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => $header,
            CURLOPT_SSLKEY => $pemPath,
            CURLOPT_SSLCERT => $crtPath,
            // CURLOPT_NOSIGNAL => 1

        ));

        $response = curl_exec($curl);


        $err = curl_error($curl);

        curl_close($curl);

        echo (json_encode($response));
        echo ("\n\n");
        if ($err) {
            return ["success" => false, "message" => $err];
        } else {
            return ["success" => true, "data" => json_decode($response)];
        }
```

But I need to do it using Http Client for many other purposes. Any suggestion?

Comment: maybe this can help [guzzle cert](https://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/request-options.html#cert)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [Guzzle options](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/http-client#guzzle-options) provided by http client

```
$response = Http::withOptions([
    'ssl_key' => ['/path/to/cert.pem', 'password.key']
])->post('https://domainname.com/api/client/session');
```

It would be same as using ssl_key request option for guzzle http client instance directly.

```
use GuzzleHttp\Client;

$client = new Client();
$client->request('POST', 'https://domainname.com/api/client/session', [
    'ssl_key' => ['/path/to/cert.pem', 'password.key']
]);
```